# Django CMS installer fails creating database

Tags: django, django-cms

I followed the tutorial presented in http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/install.html and it goes well until I want to create a project using `djangocms -f -p . mysite` then it is followed by these errors:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Akbar\Desktop\djangocmsTest\tutorial-project>djangocms -f -p . mysite
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
If I am stuck for a long time, please check for connectivity / PyPi issues
Dependencies installed
Creating the project
The installation has failed.


*****************************************************************

Check documentation at https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io

*****************************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python\python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Akbar\Desktop\djangocmsTest\venv\Scripts\djangocms.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\akbar\desktop\djangocmstest\venv\lib\site-packages\djangocms_installer\main.py", line 44, in execute
    django.setup_database(config_data)
  File "c:\users\akbar\desktop\djangocmstest\venv\lib\site-packages\djangocms_installer\django\__init__.py", line 407, in setup_database
    command, env=env, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
  File "c:\python\python37\Lib\subprocess.py", line 376, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\python\python37\Lib\subprocess.py", line 468, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\akbar\\desktop\\djangocmstest\\venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-W', 'ignore', 'manage.py', 'migrate']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

And as you see there is no questions to respond.

Comment: So it's trying to give you a default database, which is a sqlite file called `project.db`. Can you see that in the folder you're trying to run this in? If it hasn't created the file perhaps there is a permissions issue with doing that.

Comment: Maybe there is a permission problem that doesn't allow the `project.db` to be created. I can see that you're on Windows. Try running the CMD in Administrator mode.